# Sort JS object by key in descending order

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

When I try to sort my object while in for loop, it is in descending order flow, but when I try to print my object in console after sorting, it is again showing in ascending order.

```
function sortObject(object) {
    var sortedObj = {},
        keys = _.keys(object);
    var keysReverse = keys.reverse();

    _.each(keysReverse, function(key) {

        sortedObj[key] = object[key];
        console.log(sortedObj);
    });
    return sortedObj;
}

var obj5 = {
    3: 'some',
    7: 'every',
    2: 'all'
}

sortObject(obj5);
```

How can I sort the object by key in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse array will not sort the array.

```
var keysReverse = _.sortBy(keys, function(num){ return num });
```

```js
function sortObject(obj) {
  var sortedObj = {},
    keys = _.keys(obj);

  var keysReverse = _.sortBy(keys, function(num) {
    return num
  });

  _.each(keysReverse, function(key) {

    sortedObj[key] = obj[key];

  });
  return sortedObj;
}

var obj5 = {
  3: 'some',
  7: 'every',
  2: 'all'
}

console.log(sortObject(obj5));
```

```html
<script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: var keysReverse= _.sortBy(keys, function(num){ 
         return -num;
      });   As i need descending order i used this method.. but still my object is logging in ascending order  ??  like                                             {
  "2": "all",
  "3": "some",
  "7": "every"
}

Comment: @ArthiReddyPedditti Javascript objects' properties are unordered by definition; so sorting them is meaningless.

Comment: you can sort array of keys of object. but not object itself .

Comment: hi, can't we create a new object and add the properties in sorted key order ??

Comment: that's what we are doing but at the end we are getting ascending order.